# Sum values inside an array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm trying to sum the values inside an array depending on which levels they are but with no success for the moment.

Datas I'm working with ( named as the variable totalByLevel ) :

[image]

What I want :

Having each total per level inside 1 array, for example : ['total of 3 + 4', 'total of 6 + 7', etc...]

What I tried :

I tried to create an empty array and push the values from 3 + 4 into the array, which is working but not as intented.

[image]

Only the last values is kept in the array and all others are erased, if you have a fix for it I would really appreciate any help! Thank you in advance.

**component.ts**

```
for (const levelKey in this.totalByLevel ) {
        if (this.totalByLevel .hasOwnProperty(levelKey)) {
          const key = this.labelName[levelKey];
          const value = this.totalByLevel [levelKey][Object.keys(this.totalByLevel [levelKey])[0]];
          const value2 = this.labelName[Object.keys(this.totalByLevel [levelKey])[0]];
          const value3 = this.totalByLevel [levelKey][Object.keys(this.totalByLevel [levelKey])[1]];
          const value4 = this.totalByLevel [levelKey][Object.keys(this.totalByLevel [levelKey])[2]];

          this.output_object[key] = value;
          this.output_object2[key] =  value2;
          const sum = [];
          if (value4 !== undefined || null) {
            sum.push((+value + +value3 + +value4).toFixed(2));
            console.log(sum, 'SUM 3');
            this.totalPerCat = sum;

          } else if (value4 === undefined || null) {
             sum.push((+value + +value3).toFixed(2));
             console.log(sum, 'SUM 2');
             this.totalPerCat = sum;

          } else if (value3 === undefined || null) {
            sum.push(value);
            console.log(sum, 'SUM 1');
            this.totalPerCat = sum;

          }
          console.log(this.totalPerCat);
/*          console.log(value3);
          console.log(value4);
          console.log(+value + +value3 + +value4, 'SUM');*/
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: You should probably read about truthy and falsy values in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy (Not answering the question but this could greatly improved your if...else management)

Comment: @Zer0 so if I understand right, what I was doing wrong there is that I was overwriting the value inside the array each time my **else if** was triggered, am I right ?

Comment: First this and your if/else conditions are just not well put, for example `value4 !== undefined || null`: I assume you meant `value4 !== undefined || value4 !== null`? The code you wrote would just convert the null to false (due to falsy values), making it useless and only checking for undefined. But you could even take it further:
`value4 !== undefined || null` => `if (value4)`
`value4 === undefined || null` => if (!value4)`. That's the magic of truthy/falsy in JS ;)

Comment: Thank you a lot for the very good explication. I will for sure keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
const data={
    2:{3:"3514.80", 4:"7259.32"},
    5:{6:"864941.86", 7:"1076976.54"},
    8:{"":"14145.69"},
    9:{10:"223835.02", 11:"60978.31", 12:"5554.92"}
}

const result = Object.values(data).map(items => Object.values(items).map(val => Number(val)).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the funcitons `Object.values()` and Array `reduce` in combination. Try the following

```js
var totalByLevel = {
  2: {
    3: '3514.80',
    4: '7259.32'
  },
  5: {
    6: '864941.86',
    7: '1076976.54'
  }
};

var sum = Object.values(totalByLevel).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc.push(String(Object.values(curr).reduce((a, c) => a + Number(c), 0)));
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: I'm getting the following : **error TS2339: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'unknown'.**

Comment: @Zephyr: Did you give the seed value `[]` at the end of the first reduce?

Comment: Oh right! My bad sorry I rushed into it and actually didn't, works as well now!